# Impermanence is Buddha nature / Buddha nature is impermanence

Tags: impermanence, buddha-nature

Can anyone please explain these aphorism / these aphorisms?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is here to explain? Impermanence is Buddha-nature; Buddha-nature is impermanence! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, so the following is a complete guess, and I hope someone will give a better answer.

Apparently the aphorism come from [Dōgen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%8Dgen).

Dōgen has a perhaps-non-standard view of Buddha-nature, which he calls [Busshō](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussh%C5%8D_(Sh%C5%8Db%C5%8Dgenz%C5%8D)).

My guesses are:

- If according to Dōgen everything (real) is Buddha-nature then (because everything real is impermanent), therefore everything (i.e. Buddha-nature) is impermanent.
  So for example any description of Buddha-nature and anyone describing Buddha-nature and anything to which the term Buddha-nature could be applied is impermanent.
- As for the converse (i.e. impermanence is Buddha-nature), is that related to the third noble truth, or to [rise and fall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipassan%C4%81-%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a)?